# Web Authentication Using JWT

Tags: authentication, jwt

I want to use JWT for authentication puspose between my web app and a server. I made a backend call along with creadentials to pim as below.

`https://hostname:ip/rest/oauth/token`

In response, below is the data I get:

```
{
    "access_token": ":::::::::::::::::::::::",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "::::::::::::::::::::",
    "expires_in": 42199,
    "scope": "basic openid"
}
```

Now I am thinking to create a JWT token from the response I am getting from PIM. I have 2 questions here :

- How can I create the JWT token from this response data?
- How to store token related data at client side and pass it back to PIM when there are GET or POST calls after user logged-in?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: JWT usually doesn't work the way you are describing, and it is typically the server, not the client, which creates the tokens.

Comment: On client-side the tokens are usually stored in local / session storage.